# Error installing yarn : No module named 'yarnlib'

Tags: python, node.js, npm, yarnpkg

I have some trouble installing yarn.

When I run `npm install --global yarn`, it works, but I try a `yarn --version`, first it tells me that module `cliapp` cannot be found. After installing it, same problem with `ttystatus` and finally, I get a `No module named 'yarnlib'` after installing `ttystatus`.

I tried to install [dblens](https://github.com/dblens/app) with a random `npm install -g dblens` but it failed, and now when I try to run `npm uninstall yarn` I get this

```sh
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: db_lens@0.0.1-beta.1
npm ERR! Found: electron@11.0.1
npm ERR! node_modules/electron
npm ERR!   dev electron@"^11.0.1" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer electron@"^7.0.0" from browserslist-config-erb@0.0.1
npm ERR! node_modules/browserslist-config-erb
npm ERR!   dev browserslist-config-erb@"^0.0.1" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! See /home/d.maurel@gop.link/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/d.maurel@gop.link/.npm/_logs/2021-10-14T09_52_28_872Z-debug.log
```

Would you know what I can do to make yarn works ?